# How to get resources path within a jar

Tags: java, macos, resources, jar

I know there are a number of similar questions and have been thru them without success. I am probably missing something very basic.
I have html files in a ressources package within the application jar file and I need to retrieve their paths to read and update them. Here is my code :

```
URL url  = ClassLoader.class.getResource("/com/lamalva/ressources/test.html");
System.out.println(url);          
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url.toString()));
```

When I run this code from NetBeans IDE, the output is :
    file:/Users/Philippe/NetBeansProjects/Test/build/classes/com/lamalva/ressources/SatelliteQuotaMonitor.html
and the html file is open in the browser as expected but when I run the jar file from the OSX Terminal , the output is :
    jar:file:/Users/Philippe/.Trash/Test/Test.jar!/com/lamalva/ressources/SatelliteQuotaMonitor.html 
and the html file does not opened.
Whatever I do, I fail to get the path correct. I have always the "Test.jar!" in the middle.
I will greatly appreciate assistance

Comment: Why is your JAR file being executed out of your OSX trash bin? In any case, I'm fairly certain that your default browser will not know how to retrieve HTML resources from within a JAR file.

Comment: I don't know why the jar file is executed outside the trash bin. The problem I have has no simple answer. I will move my files out of the jar and include them in the zip file which is easy and should work.

Answer (score 2):

The one line answer is -

String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource().toExternalForm().

Basically getResource method gives the URL. From this URL you can extract the path by calling toExternalForm().

References: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toExternalForm()

Comment: Appears to work in my IDE, but not from a solo jar file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to read and update resources in the jar file?

You can read the contents from an input stream - use a relative path if the resource resides in the same package as the class file.

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/class/path/to/file");
```

To write, you'll likely need to read in the contents of the existing jar, modify the parts you want then write out the updated content using JarInputStream and JarOutputStream.

Comment: My resources are html files I need to update and open in default browser. I don't need to read them in the application but I need their path to open them in the browser. The html files are stored in the resources because they need javascripts in resources/scripts

Comment: A URL in java isn't necessarily a URL which a web browser can understand. You'll need to extract the jar file to a temporary location then as the browser won't be able to display files inside the jar. Have a look at java.util.jar.JarFile - you'll need to iterate over the entries() method and extract the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You need use several `ClassLoader` if you want a resource in a jar. This fragment works in AppServers too.

In this example I read from `sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar` the file located in `org.sqlite` package.

```
public class Main {

private static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resource) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String stripped = resource.startsWith("/") ? resource.substring(1) : resource;
    InputStream stream = null;
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    if (classLoader != null) {
        stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(stripped);
    }
    if (stream == null) {
        stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);
    }
    if (stream == null) {
        stream = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(stripped);
    }
    if (stream == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found: " + resource);
    }
    return stream;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // Read file from JAR sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(getResourceAsStream("org/sqlite/NativeDB.c"));
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
```

}

For more details read [Java Classloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader)

If you want update the contents, may [Jar Inspector](http://www.codeland.org) help you.

Answer (score 0):

A URL with the `!` unzipping sub protocol cannot be used in a normal browser. Just like `ssh:` (terminal access) or `smtp:`/`mailto:` (e-mail). Also "file:..../my.jar!..." is such an unusable extension of normal URLs.

There is the JTextPane/JEditorPane with limited HTML support. And some java browser projects.

Maybe embedding the java Jetty web server could be used.

Answer (score 0):

To open a resource from classpath in default platform web browser you have two options. Either extract and copy said resource to a temporary location on a file system and pass file: url. Another and probably a better option is to run an embedded web server (such as Jetty) and serve resources directly from your classpath.